# Alternative to Positive Lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to parse certain parts of a C code using regular expressions, for example:

```
    }StructureTypeDef;
         AnotherType    HwChannelType;
```

The thing I want to match is "StructureTypeDef" after the "}" symbol (but not including it), and I know I can achieve this using

```
(?<=\})\s*\w+
```

But the issue is that js does not support this last statement. Can anybody help?

Edit: Thanks all for your answers but I should have told that I need to achieve this just by using a regex, since the parsing doesn't allow extracting strings, so I need an equivalence of the regex shown above I have tried many ways but without success.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) in regex and get the captured value.

```js
var str = `}StructureTypeDef;
         AnotherType    HwChannelType;`;

console.log(str.match(/\}\s*(\w+)/)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in a group (using `()`) and fetch only the group's contents (in this case - the first group - `[1]`):

```
code.match(/}\s*(\w+)/)[1] // => "StructureTypeDef"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following pattern:

```
}\s*(\w+)\s*;
```

This gives you a capture group of one or more 'word' characters inside `}` and `;`

**Index 1** will give you `"StructureTypeDef"`.

Index 0 will give you the full captured string.

```
text.match(/}\s*(\w+)\s*;/)[1]
```